# ¿Se puede incluir un DataTable con estilo de jquery-ui en una plantilla Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap, datatables

Mi duda es la siguiente:

> ¿Se puede incluir un `DataTable` con estilo de `JQuery-ui` en una plantilla de `Bootstrap` sin que las librerías de `Bootstrap` y `JQuery-ui` causen conflicto?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres ***con estilo de jquery*? Jquery no es para estilos, supongo que te refieres a los efectos o algo parecido

Comment: estilo de jquery ui de css, que no cause conficto con estilo de bootstrap